# Enabling Input Features for Clipping Geometry on a Raster in ModelBuilder using parameters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, clip

I have a model to summarize tree heights and density using LiDAR.  It utilizes model parameters for inputs.  I can't enable the Clip option to Input Features for Clipping Geometry because the output extent is derived from a parameter.  How do I assign a default value to the model to enable the clip option while still having the model run from parameter inputs?

[image: Model parameters]

[image: Model depiction]

Answer (score 1):

In the [Clip tool's documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm), it says

> You also have the ability to use the selected features within the
>   display as the clipping extent. If a feature within the feature class
>   is selected and Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry is checked
>   (clipping_geometry is set to ClippingGeometry), then the output clips
>   out the areas that are selected. If a feature within the feature class
>   is selected but Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry is not
>   checked (set to NONE in Python), then the output clips out the minimum
>   bounding rectangle for that feature.

Basically you need to make a selection on your feature layer to have this enabled. Try using **Select Layer By Attribute** tool just after **Feature Layer**. If you want to process all features in this layer, you can use something like OBJECTID>=0.

Additionally, if you clip your DEM by creating this selection just before the **Minus**, you can get a bit of performance increase. The best would be extracting your LAS file extents first and selecting only the ones intersecting with your **Feature Layer**, provided the conversion from LAS to Raster usually the heaviest process.